# Rest API Where clause

Tags: api, rest, jira, qliksense

I'm trying to query from Rest API through Qlik sense. How to apply where condition to the rest API call.

Any answers appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does the REST API accept filter parameters? What is the REST endpoint? Ultimately without docs or guidance from the REST provider / endpoint, there isn't a single answer on the Qlik side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQL string you pass to the search() REST endpoint is what allows you to restrict a query

Comment: could you be more specific e.g. add a link to the JQL description